# Pandas dataframe rounding

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to convert a column into a float and round the values in that column to 2 decimal places.  I have:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test_data2.csv", converters={"Col1":float64})
```

How would I also round Col1 to 2 decimal places?

Comment: You can round after loading the csv using df.round({'Col1': 2})

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to float and round during reading the `csv`, you can provide your own conversion function. You can do it...

**As a `lambda`:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("test_data2.csv", converters={
    "Col1": lambda x: round(np.float64(x), 2)})
```

**As a function:**

```
def round_float(digits):
    def f(x):
        return round(np.float64(x), digits)
    return f

df = pd.read_csv("test_data2.csv", converters={"Col1": round_float(2)})
```